# What does it mean when "The Good Old Days" have several seemingly identical downloads for the same game?

Tags: ibm-pc, file-format, game

This happens for numerous games. If I search, for example, for "Spear of Destiny", I get this: https://archive.org/details/TGODFloppyCollection?and%5B%5D=spear+of+destiny&sin=

Four different entities which are all identical, then two more which are obviously separate since they are called different things.

I've tried to download and inspect the duplicates for many of the games, but can never figure out if there is any difference. They have different "numbers" and that's it. What does that mean?

The id numbers don't seem to be chronological. For example:

```
000828-SpearOfDestiny
001237-SpearOfDestiny
```

Not anywhere close to each other.

Since this is the only source online I've found for ancient PC games in any kind of coherent form, I wish to understand what exactly is the difference between these seeming dupes, as I only want one version saved. (The right one!)

Answer (score 7):

The info files fore the downloads (can be downloaded separately) show that there are two different versions of the game (1.0 and 1.4) plus two revisions of each version (1.0 with an alternative disk 1 and 1.4 with disk 1 and two having differences) Not uncommon with old games that they released several versions and never told you about it. The 'revisions' might come from someone removing a copy protection or adding their address before uploading to a BBS.

The id number is most probably a serial number used by The Good old Days, so it only shows in which order they got hold of those disk sets.